# How to show score in game via HTML5 output?

Tags: javascript, html, dart

So my HTML5 has this output

```
<output id="counter" value="0" />
```

Now my Dart has this

```
for (Gunner gunner in gunners) {
  if (bullet.checkCollision(gunner)) {
    deleteBullets.add(bullet);
    deleteGunners.add(gunner);
    int zero = 0;
    count() {
      zero = zero + 1;
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHtml = zero.toString(); 
    }
    count();
  }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is every time I kill a gunner I get the counter to go up 1 but after I kill 1 gunner and get 1 point I can't get anymore, it stays at 1 and won't keep counting my kills after the 1st kill.

Comment: You're setting `innerHTML` to `1` every time. You're not incrementing the existing value.

Comment: You need to move `int zero = 0;` outside of the function (class or toplevel).

Comment: Its crashing every time now :( whats the best way to make a function for the <output id="counter" value="0" /> value to increase by 1 each time I call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you're storing the score in is declared within your loop, so it's being created new at 0 every time. You need to declare the variable somewhere else (outside of your loop, which is not included in the code).

```dart
// Declared somewhere more global
int score = 0;
increaseScore(int incr) {
  score += incr;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHtml = score.toString(); 
}

// Your normal loop/event handlers/whatever
renderLoop() {
  // ...
  for (Gunner gunner in gunners) {
    if (bullet.checkCollision(gunner)) {
      deleteBullets.add(bullet);
      deleteGunners.add(gunner);

      increaseScore(1);
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It gives me a error I think there is something wrong because my HTML says <output id="counter" value="0" /> and the value is a string right? or the Dart score.toString(); is a string but can it change it?

Comment: It's hard to say with so little of your code (and without the error message). I don't know what `<output>` is, but maybe you should be setting its `value` instead of `innerHtml`?

Comment: oh my gosh. thank you! your code actually worked! The problem was I decided to open a duplicate of my project in Dart to test your code(so my original source won't break more) and for some reason the same errors that were happening in the original project were happening in the duplicate project. I am sure both the duplicate and the original were interacting with each other. Anyways as soon I deleted the original and kept the duplicate it worked perfectly! Thanks again! I am not sure why the speedy share 404 sigh I have bad luck... but its not needed anymore thanks to your help :)

Comment: @King Glad to hear yo sorted it :)